# Tethering stops blocks my phone's internet

Tags: tethering

I've successfully tethered my Samsung S2 to my Windows7 laptop. Connectivity's fine for the laptop now but the phone seems to be unable to reach any host. When I disconnect the tether everything works again normally. Is it possible for both devices to access the internet at the same time while tethered?